# Opening Shape Data Dialog from Page.Drop

Tags: vba, visio

I'm using Visio 2016. I have a function called "Insert_Below" in which I drop a master (e.g., "MasterA") onto a page. I have an action setup on another shape ("shp") that calls "Insert_Below" like so

```
' Action in shape sheet of shp
Actions.Row_1  -  CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.Insert_Below")

' In ThisDocument.Insert_Below
Set newShp = pg.Drop(mstr, x, y)
```

Normally when I add a shape by dragging it over from the stencil, the Shape Data Dialog opens because I have a couple shape data fields set to ask on drop. But, when the action runs I do not get a shape data dialog for the shape that's added, "newShp" above.

Can I force the dialog to open for newShp in some way?

This is a cross post on visguy.com - [Post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9039.0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understand you. Try add this line

```
newShp.Application.Docmd 1312
```